# Chrome Extensions background page window variable

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to share objects between my javascripts.. In my background.html I have:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascrpt">
      window.Something = {};
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/file1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/file2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in file1.js I have:

```
alert("1: " + window.Something);
```

and in file2.js I have:

```
alert("2: " + window.Something);
```

when I reload my extension I just get 2 alerts:

1: undefined
2: undefined

Whats the deal?! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove script written in background.html

*Use the following code instead*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/file3.js"></script>
 <script  src="js/file1.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/file2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I assume you have a folder called js

***file3.js***

```
window.Something = {};
```

For more information refer the following link

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution

Comment: You are right - Basically, no inline js, so it wasn't getting executed.. I've now fixed this, thanks.

Comment: @Sudar, Why does background page even have a window and document?